# give a group that is isomorphic to the figure.

Tags: abstract-algebra, permutations

[image]

I think if I get help with one of these I should be good on the rest.

23) is concerned with figure a) It has one symmetry and 4 possible points.

seems like it would have two elements that map to each other and 2 that map to themselves. the left and right top branch points could be mirrored or flipped but the point in the middle and the one at the bottom can only go to themselves.

so if left branch point = 1, right branch point = 2, center = 3, bottom point = 4

then I have permutations:

$id = \left( \begin{array}{cc}1&2&3&4\\1&2&3&4\end{array}\right)$

$ \sigma = \left( \begin{array}{cc}1&2&3&4\\2&1&3&4\end{array}\right)$

$\sigma^2 = id$ so thats it, two elements. so its isomorphic to groups of 2 elements like $\mathbb{Z_2}$

Comment: Yes, that is exactly correct.